# Parsing JSON data in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get the URL from the following JSON response:

```
{
    "json": {
        "errors": [],
        "data": {
            "url": "urlIWant.com",
            "id": "asdklfjads",
            "name": "sdfjklsdf"
        }
    }
}
```

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get the URL out of this response. What code do I need to access that url in Android?

Here is the latest few lines of code that I have tried to get the url.

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseStr);
 json = json.getJSONObject("data"); //Get the "data" object out of the JSON
 url = json.getString("url"); //Grab the URL from the object
 Log.d("JSON URL", url); //url is null here
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I added the latest version of the code I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be grabbing from the "json" field first before you try to access "data".

Comment: Wouldn't that be what I am doing when creating the JSON Object with the response as a parameter?

Comment: No, you're just creating a json object that has a "json" data member.  You would still need to access the "json" member before you could get to "data"

Comment: You're right. I grabbed the "json" jsonObject first and then was able to access the "data" object and then the URL.

Comment: It also looks like he is over-writing the content of the json Object with the dat attributes

Comment: Yeah, but that's fine in this case.  The issue was with not accessing the "json" field

Answer (score 0):

You could use retrofit along with GSON to do the work for you.
There are some tutorials out there teaching how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

1 liner:

```
new JSONObject(json).getJSONObject("json").getJSONObject("data").getString("url")
```